# web2py - Translate to languages

Tags: web2py

I have a menu

```
MENU([['Users', False, URL(r=request,f='user',vars=dict(forced_language=session.lang))]])
```

and I want to translate `Users` to other languages when I put `T` before it like:

```
MENU([['T('Users')', False, URL(r=request,f='user',vars=dict(forced_language=session.lang))]])
```

But it causes invalid syntax, so how can I do that?

Also, how do I use `T` to translate words in view?

I want to translate word "language" in the following line:

```
language_multiselect_form=form_factory('a',SQLField('language',db.language,requires=IS_IN_DB(db,'language.id','language.name',multiple=True)))
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have too many quotes:

```
MENU([[T('Users'), False, URL(r=request,f='user',vars=dict(forced_language=session.lang))]])
```

Comment: How to use T in view 

E.x:

`<h1>Registration Form </h1>`

Answer (score 0):

Translating strings in views in web2py should be rather easy:

```
<h2>Hello World</h2>
```

Would become:

```
<h2>{=T('Hello World')}</h2>
```

Or Even better:

```
<h2>{=XML(T('Hello World'))}</h2>
```

Use XML() to ensure proper escaping whenever possible.

Also, obviously you should have an available translation for your strings in your language dictionary for your application.